# Publicly available petabyte-scale data set?

Tags: machine-learning

Does anybody know of any data sets that are publicly available and huge (i.e., in the petabyte ballpark). Ideally, the data set would be relevant to machine learning analyses. Maybe something from the physics, chemistry, natural-language-processing domains? I guess you could say the Web itself is such a data set, but I'm looking for something a little more structured than that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: commoncrawl? http://www.commoncrawl.org/

Comment: Sadly, in chemistry, you are lucky to find kiloscale open datasets for many problems.

Answer (score 2):

The [2009 data expo](http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html) used a large dataset including all comercial airline flights in the US between 1987 and 2008.  That data by itself probably does not quite reach petabyte stage, but there are links to supplimental information including where to get weather data.  If you were to link in all the hourly weather information for all the airports and surrounding weather stations you would end up with a pretty big data set (but you would have to construct it, it does not exist as a single dataset).

Answer (score 1):

Here's some of the biggest datasets I could find in a quick search, which probably are off by a couple orders of magnitude:

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/URL+Reputation
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bag+of+Words

Maybe wikipedia is big enough and structured enough for your purposes?